# How to realize unblocked keyboard buffer windows by C/C++

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How to realize unblocked keyboard buffer windows by C/C++?

I can use `fcntl( 0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` in Linux.
But I don't known how to realize this in Windows?

Comment: Look at following Windows functions : [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx), [GeyKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Get the console input handle by calling [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or by opening the pseudo file `CONIN$`.

Then call [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), omitting the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` flag.

This gives you unbuffered console input.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use _kbhit() function on windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx

Return Value
     _kbhit returns a nonzero value if a key has been pressed. Otherwise, it returns 0.

Remarks
     The _kbhit function checks the console for a recent keystroke. If the function returns a nonzero value, a keystroke is waiting in the buffer. The program can then call _getch or _getche to get the keystroke.

Routine Required header
  _kbhit

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.